# Win 10 CMD. Using IF GEQ to compare, getting bad results

Tags: batch-file, math, cmd, windows-10

I've been writing a CMD BATCH file to draw some stuff on the screen with ascii chars. I wrote a pretty simple setup to make circles on the screen using a variant of the distance formula. BUT the results aren't quite right.

While it draws circles (mostly), the top and left side have some weirdness going on. To attempt to debug this, I spit out the actual results of the set `/A` into a .csv and it looks like the math is being done right, and it's getting the correct result. BUT when it uses an `if !variable! geq` number, it's not reliably evaluating correctly (just MOST of the time).

Here is a stripped down version of the code that is still having the issue:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@ECHO OFF
CLS
MODE CON: COLS=100 LINES=102
COLOR 0A
IF EXIST OUTPUT.MAP DEL OUTPUT.MAP
IF EXIST MATHCHECK.CSV DEL MATHCHECK.CSV
SET STATUSLINE=-
FOR /L %%Y IN (2,1,79) DO (
    FOR /L %%X IN (2,1,79) DO (
        SET DRAWCHAR%%X%%Y=.
    )
    CLS
    ECHO !STATUSLINE!
    SET STATUSLINE=!STATUSLINE!-
)

SET STATUSLINE=-
FOR /L %%Y IN (2,1,79) DO (
    FOR /L %%X IN (2,1,79) DO (
        SET /A "SQDISTANCE=((405-%%X*10)*(405-%%X*10))+((405-%%Y*10)*(405-%%Y*10))"
        IF !SQDISTANCE! GEQ 129600 SET DRAWCHAR%%X%%Y=^^
        ECHO 129600,^^^^,%%X,%%Y,!SQDISTANCE!,!DRAWCHAR%%X%%Y!>>MATHCHECK.CSV
    )
    CLS
    ECHO !STATUSLINE!
    SET STATUSLINE=!STATUSLINE!-
 ) 

SET STATUSLINE=-
FOR /L %%Y IN (2,1,79) DO (
    FOR /L %%X IN (2,1,79) DO (
        SET /A "SQDISTANCE=((405-%%X*10)*(405-%%X*10))+((405-%%Y*10)*(405-%%Y*10))"
        IF !SQDISTANCE! GEQ 144400 SET DRAWCHAR%%X%%Y=M
        ECHO 144400,M,%%X,%%Y,!SQDISTANCE!,!DRAWCHAR%%X%%Y!>>MATHCHECK.CSV
    )
    CLS
    ECHO !STATUSLINE!
    SET STATUSLINE=!STATUSLINE!-
 )          

SET STATUSLINE=-
FOR /L %%Y IN (2,1,79) DO (
    SET DRAWLINE%%Y=-
    FOR /L %%X IN (2,1,79) DO (
        SET DRAWLINE%%Y=!DRAWLINE%%Y!!DRAWCHAR%%X%%Y!
    )
    SET DRAWLINE%%Y=!DRAWLINE%%Y:~1,79!
    ECHO !DRAWLINE%%Y!>>OUTPUT.MAP
    CLS
    ECHO COMPILING OUTPUT...
    ECHO !STATUSLINE!
    SET STATUSLINE=!STATUSLINE!-
)    

CLS
ECHO +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
FOR /L %%D IN (2,1,79) DO (
    ECHO ^|!DRAWLINE%%D!^|!                   ^|
)
ECHO +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
PAUSE
```

Here's the results I'm getting:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Rwp2YCBwJCArkVunqBNXa3CDuJhTSVSm

That SHOULD look like a square of Ms with a circle of ^s in it and then a circle of .s in that. It's mostly right but those extra jags of Ms and ^s on the top and left shouldn't be there.

Math formula SHOULD be right. it's just `A^2+B^2=C^2`.

For figuring this out, I'm spitting out a mathcheck.csv file that has:

1. The test value
2. The char to print if geq the test value
3. The x and y coord
4. The calculated squared distance from center
5. The resulting character the program said to use.

If you scroll through that file, you can see instances where the results are that the calculated value is greater than the test value even when they are NOT.

I've tried all sorts of stuff: using lss instead of geq (and flipping values), looking up and tweaking the set /a command, lookin up and tweaking the if, "drawing" in a different order (if you draw all Ms, then draw smaller circles on top instead of starting with .s and putting rings over that you get a very similar error in the same general area).

Pretty sure at this point I've either boneheaded up something obvious in the code OR that if comparisons of numbers just aren't reliable enough for this to work? that doesn't seem possible though. It HAS to be a code error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with XY coordinates is that if you don't separate them, you can have multiple values appear to be the same location. For example, [638] is either [6,38] or [63,8]. Unfortunately, if you don't separate them, batch will overwrite any existing values. Using a standard array syntax `!DRAWCHAR[%%X][%%Y]!` resolves this issue.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@ECHO OFF
CLS
MODE CON: COLS=100 LINES=102
COLOR 0A
IF EXIST OUTPUT.MAP DEL OUTPUT.MAP
IF EXIST MATHCHECK.CSV DEL MATHCHECK.CSV
SET STATUSLINE=-
FOR /L %%Y IN (2,1,79) DO (
    FOR /L %%X IN (2,1,79) DO (
        SET DRAWCHAR[%%X][%%Y]=.
    )
    CLS
    ECHO !STATUSLINE!
    SET STATUSLINE=!STATUSLINE!-
)

SET STATUSLINE=-
FOR /L %%Y IN (2,1,79) DO (
    FOR /L %%X IN (2,1,79) DO (
        SET /A "SQDISTANCE=((405-%%X*10)*(405-%%X*10))+((405-%%Y*10)*(405-%%Y*10))"
        IF !SQDISTANCE! GEQ 129600 SET DRAWCHAR[%%X][%%Y]=^^
        ECHO 129600,^^^^,%%X,%%Y,!SQDISTANCE!,!DRAWCHAR[%%X][%%Y!]>>MATHCHECK.CSV
    )
    CLS
    ECHO !STATUSLINE!
    SET STATUSLINE=!STATUSLINE!-
 ) 

SET STATUSLINE=-
FOR /L %%Y IN (2,1,79) DO (
    FOR /L %%X IN (2,1,79) DO (
        SET /A "SQDISTANCE=((405-%%X*10)*(405-%%X*10))+((405-%%Y*10)*(405-%%Y*10))"
        IF !SQDISTANCE! GEQ 144400 SET DRAWCHAR[%%X][%%Y]=M
        ECHO 144400,M,%%X,%%Y,!SQDISTANCE!,!DRAWCHAR[%%X][%%Y]!>>MATHCHECK.CSV
    )
    CLS
    ECHO !STATUSLINE!
    SET STATUSLINE=!STATUSLINE!-
 )          

SET STATUSLINE=-
FOR /L %%Y IN (2,1,79) DO (
    SET DRAWLINE[%%Y]=-
    FOR /L %%X IN (2,1,79) DO (
        SET DRAWLINE[%%Y]=!DRAWLINE[%%Y]!!DRAWCHAR[%%X][%%Y]!
    )
    SET DRAWLINE[%%Y]=!DRAWLINE[%%Y]:~1,79!
    ECHO !DRAWLINE[%%Y]!>>OUTPUT.MAP
    CLS
    ECHO COMPILING OUTPUT...
    ECHO !STATUSLINE!
    SET STATUSLINE=!STATUSLINE!-
)    

CLS
ECHO +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
FOR /L %%D IN (2,1,79) DO (
    ECHO ^|!DRAWLINE[%%D]!^|!                   ^|
)
ECHO +------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
PAUSE
```

Comment: Yes! Absolutely! Thanks so much! changing my variable name to !DRAWCHAR%%X,%%Y! fixed the mess! I suppose I could also get around it by using:
    set xpos=0%%X
    set xpos=!xpos:~--2!
    same for y 
    set DRAWCHAR!xpos!!ypos!

But that feels like it would be more processor cycles.